# Cannot search YouTube videos by developer tag

Tags: youtube-api

Search https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=%7Bhttp://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/developertags.cat%7Dmy_developer_tag&v=2&key=my_developer_key by developer tag does consistently return 0 results. Developer tag exists in at least one video I am looking for.

```
...<openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults>...
```

It is pretty good explained in documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing#Browsing_with_Categories_and_Keywords but it simply does not work

I am sending my developer key in both 'X-GData-Key' header and 'key' parameter in URL and I have tested a few days after video upload, so it is not a matter of propagation time.

Request is authenticated what I can confirm by getting developer tag when I issue query based on generic search  phrase.

My simple question is how to search all YouTube videos by developer key so I can select only videos uploaded by my application?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the documented behavior and things are working as expected for me. It takes a couple of hours for the video to show up in the search index, but once it does, developer-tag based searches also find it.

You can determine whether a video has made it into the search index or not by requesting http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=**VIDEO_ID** and trying every so often until it returns a result. (That assumes the **VIDEO_ID** doesn't start with a '-' character...)

Once you're sure it's in the index, a request for https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=%7Bhttp://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/developertags.cat%7D**DEVELOPER_TAG**&v=2&key=**DEVELOPER_KEY** should return it. You don't need to include `Authorization` headers when doing that search—you just need to make sure you're using the same **DEVELOPER_KEY** and **DEVELOPER_TAG** values you used when performing the initial upload.

Comment: It does not work for me. So you are telling that I do not need Authorization header to query this request. Is it OK with you to share this exact query with me so I could test it myself and compare to my query and try to determine what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no time delay or some other delay at all. Videos simply cannot be searched by developer tag. I ended up setting subject of the video to my identifier, so I search all videos with that specific identifier as a generic query and eliminate ones that do not contain developer tag. So it exists, but cannot be searched by.